# Starting Multiple Oracle 12c Listeners on Startup

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I will edit the original post because now we're breaking down the original problem and I even have to twist the original question too. As for those that join now. I encountered a problem when configuring multiple oracle instances/listeners to start-up automatically in Oracle EL6.
I'm using the following script to handle the startups:

```
#!/bin/sh
# chkconfig 345 99 10

export ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1
export ORACLE_OWNER=oracle

if [ ! -f $ORACLE_HOME/bin/dbstart ]
then
    echo "Oracle startup: cannot start"
    exit
fi

case "$1" in
    'start')
        # Start the Oracle databases:
        su $ORACLE_OWNER -c "$ORACLE_HOME/bin/dbstart $ORACLE_HOME" &
        su $ORACLE_OWNER -c "$ORACLE_HOME/bin/lsnrctl start TEST.LOCALHOST" &
        su $ORACLE_OWNER -c "$ORACLE_HOME/bin/lsnrctl start CAPEX" &
        touch /var/lock/subsys/dbora
        ;;
    'stop')
        # Stop the Oracle databases:
        su $ORACLE_OWNER -c "$ORACLE_HOME/bin/dbshut $ORACLE_HOME"
        su $ORACLE_OWNER -c "$ORACLE_HOME/bin/lsnrctl stop TEST.LOCAHOST"
        su $ORACLE_OWNER -c "$ORACLE_HOME/bin/lsnrctl stop CAPEX"
        rm -f /var/lock/subsys/dbora
        ;;
esac
```

This file is located under /etc/init.d/ folder. The file itself is called dbora. I've also added it to the startup with chkconfig --add. The status of it aka the output of chkconfig --list is the following:

```
[root@localhost ~]# chkconfig --list
NetworkManager  0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
abrt-ccpp       0:off   1:off   2:off   3:on    4:off   5:on    6:off
abrt-oops       0:off   1:off   2:off   3:on    4:off   5:on    6:off
abrtd           0:off   1:off   2:off   3:on    4:off   5:on    6:off
acpid           0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
atd             0:off   1:off   2:off   3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
auditd          0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
autofs          0:off   1:off   2:off   3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
blk-availability    0:off   1:on    2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
bluetooth       0:off   1:off   2:off   3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
certmonger      0:off   1:off   2:off   3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
cgconfig        0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
cgred           0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
cpuspeed        0:off   1:on    2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
crond           0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
cups            0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
dbora           0:off   1:off   2:off   3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
dnsmasq         0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
firstboot       0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
haldaemon       0:off   1:off   2:off   3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
htcacheclean    0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
httpd           0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
ip6tables       0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
iptables        0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
irqbalance      0:off   1:off   2:off   3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
kdump           0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
lvm2-monitor    0:off   1:on    2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
mcelogd         0:off   1:off   2:off   3:on    4:off   5:off   6:off
mdmonitor       0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
messagebus      0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
netconsole      0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
netfs           0:off   1:off   2:off   3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
network         0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
nfs             0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
nfslock         0:off   1:off   2:off   3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
ntpd            0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
ntpdate         0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
numad           0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
oddjobd         0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
portreserve     0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
postfix         0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
psacct          0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
quota_nld       0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
rdisc           0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
restorecond     0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
rhnsd           0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
rngd            0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
rpcbind         0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
rpcgssd         0:off   1:off   2:off   3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
rpcsvcgssd      0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
rsyslog         0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
saslauthd       0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
smartd          0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
spice-vdagentd  0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:on    6:off
sshd            0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
sssd            0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
svnserve        0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
sysstat         0:off   1:on    2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
udev-post       0:off   1:on    2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
vmware-tools    0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
vmware-tools-thinprint  0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
wdaemon         0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
winbind         0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
wpa_supplicant  0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
xinetd          0:off   1:off   2:off   3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
ypbind          0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off

xinetd based services:
    chargen-dgram:  off
    chargen-stream: off
    daytime-dgram:  off
    daytime-stream: off
    discard-dgram:  off
    discard-stream: off
    echo-dgram:     off
    echo-stream:    off
    rsync:          off
    tcpmux-server:  off
    time-dgram:     off
    time-stream:    off
```

After restarting the system I checked the two listener's log files which now contained the following entries:

```
For CAPEX listener:
<msg time='2013-12-17T14:16:44.440+01:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='localhost.localdomain'
 host_addr='::1'>
    <txt>17-DEC-2013 14:16:44 * service_update * CAPEX * 0</txt>
</msg>

For TEST.LOCALOHOST listener:
<msg time='2013-12-17T14:16:46.880+01:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='localhost.localdomain'
 host_addr='::1'>
    <txt>17-DEC-2013 14:16:46 * service_update * TEST * 0</txt>
</msg>
```

I also tried to check wheteher the listeners are running via executing the following command (As I found neither of them are actually running):

```
[root@localhost ~]# ps -ef | grep tnslsnr | grep -v grep
[root@localhost ~]#
```

As I also tried to check if the actual database instances are running I also found that they're in idle state which for me means not running. Maybe now you have some idea what is going on, what I mess up.

Thanks,
 Joe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ORACLE_HOME` isn't set in the `su` environment. The full path to the `lsnrctl` binary is being provided because `$ORACLE_HOME` is being expanded before `su` is called, so you're really doing:

```
su oracle -c "/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/bin/lsnrctl start CAPEX" &
```

When you run it manually `ORACLE_HOME` is set, so it works. When run through `su` it isn't, but it still finds the binary since it has the full path. `dbstart` works because it resets `ORACLE_HOME` from the `oratab` entries as it processes them. The 'no message file' error is usually an indicator that `ORACLE_HOME` isn't set, and the permission error the code refers suggests it's looking for the `listener.ora` in the wrong place, presumably under the root directory.

You can demonstrate this by having the script try to display the value:

```
su $ORACLE_OWNER -c "ORACLE_HOME is: \$ORACLE_HOME`"
```

You could set the `ORACLE_HOME` in the command you're running through `su`, as:

```
su $ORACLE_OWNER -c "ORACLE_HOME=$ORACLE_HOME;$ORACLE_HOME/bin/lsnrctl start CAPEX" &
```

But it's simpler to `export` the variables in your script, which will make them visible to `su`:

```
export ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1
export ORACLE_OWNER=oracle
```

or

```
ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1
ORACLE_OWNER=oracle
export ORACLE_HOME ORACLE_OWNER
```

... depending on your shell.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I modified the bash script according to your answer. Now I get no error message at startup but neither the listeners are started nor the database.

Comment: Do you get the messages you're echoing, and any banners etc. from the commands? Can you add more debugs to pinpoint when it's failing? Also you said it's a bash script - you haven't shown it, do you have `#!/bin/bash` at the top? Wondering if that export form is confusing root's default shell during boot. What happens if you run the script manually as root?

Comment: you should check the alert.log and listener.log files.

Comment: Updated the original question according to the new informations.

Comment: @Joey - your edited version looks like it shouldn't do anything, because your first test is now referring to `$ORA_HOME`, which isn't set. The listener log messages are confusing though, unless you later started themmanually. Passing `$ORACLE_HOME` to `dbstart` should just mean it starts the default listener, and you don't have a default... but then it shouldn't be getting that far at the moment.

Comment: I found the problem. I had a proxy configured that didn't allow 192.x.x.x ip address accesses. After disabling that I can access the databases from the remote computer. Thank you for your help!

Comment: OK... doesn't really explain why you couldn't see the listener processes and why the DB said it was idle, but as long as you're happy, that's the main thing *8-)